# Does lying in your bed, unable to sleep, in fact count as meaningful rest?

Tags: sleep, sleep-deprivation

Many nights, I cannot sleep. Even if I go to bed around midnight, I might lie there until 5 in the morning or later before I finally fall asleep, and then usually wake up way too early due to noises.

I don't drink coffee for many hours before I start attempting to sleep. I even use sleeping pills in maximum dosage lately. This happens even if I've been physically active during the day. I even have a floor fan on and two different whitenoise generators to make it easier for me to sleep. I can be deadly tired and still just lie there, unable to sleep. The room is completely dark.

I might be permanently destroyed mentally and physically from long-term stress and anxiety. I always have had problems sleeping, even as a child, but it was never this extreme.

I wonder if there is some health benefit to lying in my bed like this for hours and hours every night without actually sleeping (but merely *trying*). At least I'm not moving around or sitting in front of a computer, so logically, it should provide some sort of "rest", no? However, in practice, it doesn't *feel* like I've "rested"; I become a complete zombie with basically anything less than 6 hours of sleep, with 5 being very much on the lower edge, and four and below guarantees me turning into zombie mode. (But even those 4-hour-sleep days, I *still* often have trouble sleeping again the next night!)

Comment: Questions requesting personal medical advice are off-topic here. It would be inappropriate for anyone to attempt to address your health issues. Such questions should be taken to your personal physician who can examine you and access your full medical records. For more information, please see [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/748/805).